# How to register multiple target groups via aws ecs cli service command

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have currently deployed a web server via aws `ecs cli compose service up` cli command, and I further registered a domain in route 53 service, register a certificate through Amazon Certificate Manager. Making use of the ALB (application load balancer), I am able to perform dynamic port mapping and https for my web application, but here is the problem.

Using docker compose as the blueprint for my web application, which consists of 3 containers, frontend, loopback and database (mongo), my frontend container's dynamic port mapping and https are up and running fine

[image]

However the problem comes to the loopback container, there are chances frontend needs to fetch something via loopback API server (which makes use of 3002 port), but the loopback container does not is not have configured in https which causes the error below when calling the API.

[image]

Through `ecs cli compose service up` command, I can configure the target group to allow elb to forward the request to frontend container (using `--target-group-arn`, `--container-name` and `--container-port` attributes to specify the frontend container with the specific target group), but this command seems unable to map the 2nd target group to my loopback container. Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html which seems to allow the possibility of multiple target groups for a service, but I cannot figure out how to use `create service` command to link up my docker containers without using user `ecs cli compose service up` command.

Is there a way to

1. Use `ecs cli compose service up` command to register multiple target groups on my containers?
2. Apply https also on my loopback URL (which domain name is `myDomain.com:3002`)?

======================================================

Follow-up tasks

1. Created 2 target groups

[image]

2. Configured rules and listeners

[image]
[image]

3. Knowing ecs cli service up cannot register multiple groups, I tried to do via console, still only 1 container can be registered
   [image]

Thanks and appreciate for all helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ecs cli compose service up` contains a parameter `--target-groups` allowing you to add multiple target groups at once.

```
ecs-cli compose --file "../../src/docker-compose.yml" `
                --ecs-params "../../src/ecs-params.yml" `
                --project-name xxxxx service up  `
                --target-groups "targetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-3:xxxxx:targetgroup/xxxx_tg1,containerPort=80,containerName=webapi" `
                --target-groups "targetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-3:xxxxx:targetgroup/xxxx_tg2,containerPort=81,containerName=webapi2" `
                --cluster-config myconfig`
                --ecs-profile myprofile
```

[ecs-cli compose service up documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-service-up.html)

Comment: thanks, I found they update the command allowing more target-groups to be specified now, better if they can introduce earlier...

Answer (score 4):

1. As far your question is a concern, it possible to perform that using AWS console, but `ecs cli` currently [does not support multiple target group](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/910) at the moment.

you can check this [ecs-cli compose service up with a load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898568/ecs-cli-compose-service-up-with-a-load-balancer/53937629) also consider this [amazon-ecs-cli-register-service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html).

2. The second error occurred when the frontend application tries to use load mix `HTTP` and `https` resources. you can look into the error, there can be static or API calls that are based on `HTTP`, convert all these calls to `HTTPS` then it should work fine. you can check error seems like static file loading from http site.

Once you applied `HTTPS` it should point to `https://example.com` or `https://api.example.com`, the port is not required with HTTPs call if its bind with standard HTTPS port.

Update:

ALB target group route traffic base on the target group, so the target group contain the desired container. adding screenshot to make it more clear.
[image]

Comment: thanks Adiii, yes I am more or less with the same idea as yours, but first 1 more target group is needed, because loopback server needs 3002 (host port)  to receive request (guess I cannot use 80 as it will conflict with the frontend container?), in this case I need 1 more load balancer to listen for 3002 port and correctly map the request to the internal container, that's the reason I am finding a way to get 2 target groups, each of them mapping to 80 and 3002 respectively

Comment: you can take advantage of ALB routing feature. both will bind port 80 and `example.com` will point to frontend container and `api.example.com` will point to backend container.

Comment: And i am thinking of changing the `example.com:3002` to `api.example.com`, but I just registered `example.com` and `www.example.com` (alias) in the aws certificate manager, if I also want `https://api.example.com`, do I need to do another registeration?

Comment: Thanks again Adiii, but I think ALB routing feature did allow me to listen to request of `api.example.com` and do the redirection, but I think it does not have rules to map such request to specific container ? Like if user requests for `api.example.com`, it will forward to container named `loopback` -> I think it does not support??

Comment: yes exactly, better to add `*` in your certificate. and routing feature looking for target group not to container. so `backend` target group will handle traffic `api.example.com` and frontend targetgroup will hand traffic of `example.com`

Comment: but without registering loopback container to backend target group, how do the load balancer know which container it needs to forward the request to ? From the capture, I think I need to register loopback container to nodeapi target group?

Comment: you need two target group one for backend and one for frontend.

Comment: Thanks Adiii, my only problem remains now is how I can register multiple target groups, actually I have read the reference sites provided https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html before, and it only provides a loadBalancer object for reference, which I am confused... Is this `loadBalancer` config only applies to `create-service` command? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html

Comment: once you create two target group, you do not need multiple target group. both will serverd with own target group.

Comment: Sorry for my dumb, but I can't still quite get it. I have changed all port based api to api.example.com, and added https on them, I then created 2 target groups now (as illustrated at 1st post), 1 for frontend and 1 for loopback. As I can only add register 1 pair (frontend container in gme-gp), but not both via cli command, I think I also need to register 1 more pair (loopback container in gme-loopback-gp) which I am still not finding a way to accomplish

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209241/discussion-between-adiii-and-user2361494).